# Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\App_Data' is denied

Tags: asp.net, iis, access-denied

I just installed IIS on Windows XP.

When I try to execute an app, I get an error:

> Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\App_Data' is denied.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\App_Data' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 70:     Protected Sub cmbSettingFiles_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal
>   sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles
>   cmbSettingFiles.SelectedIndexChanged
>   Line 71:  Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
>   Line 72: doc.Load(Path.Combine(basePath, cmbSettingFiles.SelectedValue)) 
>   Line 74: Dim settingsNode As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/settings")
>
> Source File: C:\myapp\install\install.aspx.vb    Line: 72

I have tried grating permission by doing this:

> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.

But the error persists.

Does this have anything to do with my code?

How can I resolve this?

**EDIT**

I have solved the problem on my dev machine, but I am still getting the error on my web server.

Thanks.

Comment: Am the only one using the file on my dev machine, and when i upload ti my server online, the same thing happens also .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Try to go to App_Data folder property and add ASPNET user with read
>   and write privileges

Ref:
[How to assign correct permissions to App_Data folder of WebMail Pro ASP.NET](http://www.afterlogic.com/kb/articles/how-to-assign-correct-permissions-to-appdata-folder-of-webmail-pro-aspnet)
[Permissions on APP_DATA Folder](http://forums.asp.net/t/920414.aspx/1)
[ASP/ASP.NET Best way to handle write permissions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/14655/asp-asp-net-best-way-to-handle-write-permissions)

If it does not solve your problem then check whether your XML files are not open by another thread using these configuration files.. and provide some more details if still persists.

Comment: hello, can you help me look at the new error. am getting the same error in web server

Answer (score 35):

If you're getting this error, you're probably trying to write to `wwwroot`. By default this is not allowed, [for good reason](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47399140#47399140).

Instead, consider storing your files somewhere besides `wwwroot`. If you just need to serve the files, store them in a folder *outside* of `inetpub` and use a [virtual directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) to make them visible to IIS.

Original answer:

---

**For those running IIS on Windows Server:**

By default, the IIS user does not have write permissions for the `wwwroot` folder. This can be solved by granting full permissions to the `IIS_IUSRS` user for `wwwroot`.

1. Open File Explorer and go to `C:/inetpub/`
2. Right click on wwwroot and click on "Properties"
3. Go to the Security tab and click "Edit..." to edit permissions
4. Find and select the IIS user. In my case, it was called `IIS_IUSRS ([server name]\IIS_IUSRS)`.
5. Select the "Allow" checkbox for all permissions.

Comment: This answer really saved my time.

Comment: Just to emphasis that IIS_IUSRS users might/should be already there, step 5 above is the key, allow ALL permissions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 10):

Consider if your file is read only, then the extra parameters may help with `FileStream`

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are adding the correct user? Have you checked to see which user is set for your applications app pool?

This error will also happen if it cannot read the file for some reason; such as the file is locked or used by another application. Since this is an ASP.NET web application you will want to make sure you are not performing any actions that would require the file to be locked; unless you can guarantee you will only have one user on your page at a time.

Can you post an example of how you access the file? What type of file is it? Code snippets will help you get a more exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation.  I am using TFS for source code control.  What I found is that when it was checked in, it made the files readonly.  This caused the above error in my service where it was opening them read/write.  Once I checked them out for edit.  Everything worked great.  I am considering trying opening them readonly in the service.  I think that once they get published to the production server, this is not an issue.  Only in the development environment.  I have seen similar issues with Services that use Entity Framework.  If the .svc file is checked in, you can't do updates to the database through EF.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to add ASP.net v4.0 with all permission, add NETWORK SERVICE user but nothing help.
At last, added the MODIFY right of DefaultAppPool user in App_Data folder, problem solved.

Comment: This worked for me too.  A new server and my deployment package didn't even create an app_data folder.  I created it and then added the modify rights to DefaultAppPool

Answer (score 1):

Please Run Visual Studio with Administrator privilege..This Issue is solved for me..

**Access to the path is denied C:\inetpub\wwwroot**
is denied indicates that the Self Service web site can’t access a specific folder on the server where it is installed. 
This could be either because the location doesn’t exist, or because the Authenticating User does not have any permissions applied to Write to this location.

Answer (score 0):

Try granting permission to the NETWORK SERVICE user.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be because the filepath is empty where you are trying to write which is why it can't find it. just another reason why this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

For me i had already created a folder with name excel in wwroot
D:\working directory\OnlineExam\wwwroot\excel
And i was trying to copy a file with name excel which was already existing as a folder name. the path which was required was
D:\working directory\OnlineExam\wwwroot\excel\finance.csv
so according i changed the code as below

```
string copyPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "excel\\finance");
                    questionExcelUpload.Upload.CopyTo(new FileStream(copyPath, FileMode.Create));
```

**Basically check if a folder or a file with same name as your path exist already.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent on it more time that I'd admit, especially since I was able to WRITE files to the same folder.

Only after testing a dozen other things I realized that my "path" variable only had the directory, and no filename! Bad, bad error message!

Before:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SpecialFolder");
```

After:

```
string path = Path.Combine(
      Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SpecialFolder"),
      filename); //NOTE: will cause Access Denied if filename is missing or empty!
```

It's possible the original error was also not due to denied access, but because the selected "filename" was an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the answer for 2019.  You need to add 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' to the list of users that have security rights to the directory that is to be modified.  Make sure they have full rights.

Answer (score -1):

I created copy of my inet folder, to make a duplicate of the site. It showed 'access denied .../App_Data/viewstate/1/6/6/0 ... '. On checking it showed that app_data folder is having IIS_IUSER addes but does not have modify or write acess checked. Just check those boxes and the instance begin to run.