# Access to App_Data path where ldf file is denied when checking in with Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, access-denied, team-explorer, app-data

I can't seem to check in my changes to Team Foundation Server. I get the "Access to path App_Data is denied". So I googled it and found this link on Stackoverflow [Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\App_Data' is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255790/access-to-the-path-c-inetpub-wwwroot-myapp-app-data-is-denied)

But I tried to add the permission for the folder by unchecking read only and it says after you make the changes you will need admin permission. So I hit ok and then nothing happens. I then go back into the permissions tab and see that the red only option is still checked. Not sure what I need to do here. I also don't see anyone else besides me that I can share permissions with. I'm the only user on this machine and I think I have admin rights.

MVC 5 application with Sql Server Express and Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: So...  You're trying to check in your database to source control?

Comment: yes well I've read different views on this. I know I shouldn't technically be checking it into source control, but then how do I save the database structure/tables/views/indexes/etc/etc incase I loose it somewhere in the future? I thought that was what the mdf file was for? As long as you don't store real data into it and only test data, the file stays very small!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I had to detach my database from SQl Server Express in order to check in and check out. By detaching from my database in Sql Server Management Studio access was given and the ldf file was unlocked. But this seems really burdensome if I'm checking in and out all the time. I don't want to have to attach and detach every time I want to check in and check out of source control in Visual Studio Team Services.
Am I missing something here. Is there a way to check in .ldf files when my database is attached??

I'm using SQl Server Express 2014 and VS 2013 and Team Services as source control. Note - I'm not using localdb because I created full text searching features in my app and localdb doesn't support it.